# Why is there a 'name' argument inside 'scale_x/y_continuous()' functions in ggplot, when already 'x/ylab()' functions exist?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I suppose the `name` argument in `scale_x_continuous()` and `scale_y_continuous()` functions in ggplot, only changes the axis labels, and so do the `xlab()` and `ylab()` functions.

So, what's the need of this argument in those functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions does not have the same purpose and you will have to use depending of what you want to do.

`scale_x_continuous` and `scale_y_continuous` not only allow you to change the name of the corresponding axis but also to customize the axis (by modifying the limits,  the breaks, the scale, adding a second axis, ...). Whereas `xlab` and `ylab` functions only modify the name of the corresponding axis.

Let's take an example. You have a scatter plot and you want to modify the limits and the name of x axis. Without `scale_x_continuous`, you will write:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x, y, ...) +
    geom_point()+
    xlab("New Name")+
    xlim(0,10)
```

With `scale_x_continuous`, you can write:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x, y, ...) +
    geom_point()+
    scale_x_continuous(name = "New Name", limits = c(0,10))
```

So, you have one less line and potentially, you can pass more arguments to `scale_x_continuous`.

But if we take the same example, but you only need to change the name of the title, you can do either:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x, y, ...) +
    geom_point()+
    xlab("New Name")
```

or

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, y, ...) +
    geom_point()+
    scale_x_continuous(name = "New Name")
```

Now, you see that the use of `xlab` is much more convenient and readable.

To my personal opinion, the purpose of these redundant functions is to various ways to obtain what you desire while keeping things simple and readable. All of these functions are useful but it is up to you to use them depending of what you need to do.

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labs.html
https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html

Answer (score 1):

These type of functions were created, because of sometimes you want to do something manual in the axes, these functions can help you to do those. I hope this link will be useful to you:
https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html